# Running an external script in a VAST tag

Tags: javascript, video, ads, vast

I have a 3rd party script (which does some data analysis in the client browser) that usually gets appended to an ad creative on a display ad.

I would like to append this script to a video ad, using a VAST tag.  I have read the VAST spec, and I have not found an example of running a script in the browser - just examples of calling a server upon specific events.

Can anybody point me to an example of how to append a script to a VAST tag so that it can run code in the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the regular VAST standard does not cover adding custom scripts to the web page you delivering ads to. You could use VPAID to do this or use a VAST Extension. Extensions can be more or less freely configured, but of course such an extension will only work in players which support this extension.

If you do not have control of the player, try using VPAID -- or find a better (simpler) way to track what you need. VAST video advertisement is different from display ads, you can use simple tracking pixels, but no scripts.